# How to implement gabor filters on 3D images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, feature-extraction

I am working with 3D images, and I would like to implement Gabor features. For this purpose, I need to generate Gabor filter banks with different scale and orientation (maybe in 3D, two angles) and then convalve them with my image. My question is that is there any possibility to implement 3D gabor filters and then convalve them with 3D images. Or do I have do in in 2D slice by slice. If so, any suggestion to implement it in matlab would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it 2D.
Gabor filter is automatically change your image to grayscale, so being 3D is becoming useless anyway.

here is a gabor filter for matlab, I used it and it is perfectly working.

```
function gaborArray = gaborFilterBank(u,v,m,n)

% GABORFILTERBANK generates a custum Gabor filter bank. 
% It creates a u by v array, whose elements are m by n matries; 
% each matrix being a 2-D Gabor filter.
% 
% 
% Inputs:
%       u   :   No. of scales (usually set to 5) 
%       v   :   No. of orientations (usually set to 8)
%       m   :   No. of rows in a 2-D Gabor filter (an odd integer number usually set to 39)
%       n   :   No. of columns in a 2-D Gabor filter (an odd integer number usually set to 39)
% 
% Output:
%       gaborArray: A u by v array, element of which are m by n 
%                   matries; each matrix being a 2-D Gabor filter   
% 
% 
% Sample use:
% 
% gaborArray = gaborFilterBank(5,8,39,39);
% 
% 
%   Details can be found in:
%   
%   M. Haghighat, S. Zonouz, M. Abdel-Mottaleb, "Identification Using 
%   Encrypted Biometrics," Computer Analysis of Images and Patterns, 
%   Springer Berlin Heidelberg, pp. 440-448, 2013.
% 
% 
% (C)   Mohammad Haghighat, University of Miami
%       haghighat@ieee.org
%       I WILL APPRECIATE IF YOU CITE OUR PAPER IN YOUR WORK.



if (nargin ~= 4)    % Check correct number of arguments
    error('There should be four inputs.')
end


%% Create Gabor filters

% Create u*v gabor filters each being an m*n matrix

gaborArray = cell(u,v);
fmax = 0.25;
gama = sqrt(2);
eta = sqrt(2);

for i = 1:u

    fu = fmax/((sqrt(2))^(i-1));
    alpha = fu/gama;
    beta = fu/eta;

    for j = 1:v
        tetav = ((j-1)/v)*pi;
        gFilter = zeros(m,n);

        for x = 1:m
            for y = 1:n
                xprime = (x-((m+1)/2))*cos(tetav)+(y-((n+1)/2))*sin(tetav);
                yprime = -(x-((m+1)/2))*sin(tetav)+(y-((n+1)/2))*cos(tetav);
                gFilter(x,y) = (fu^2/(pi*gama*eta))*exp(-((alpha^2)*(xprime^2)+(beta^2)*(yprime^2)))*exp(1i*2*pi*fu*xprime);
            end
        end
        gaborArray{i,j} = gFilter;

    end
end


%% Show Gabor filters

% Show magnitudes of Gabor filters:
figure('NumberTitle','Off','Name','Magnitudes of Gabor filters');
for i = 1:u
    for j = 1:v        
        subplot(u,v,(i-1)*v+j);        
        imshow(abs(gaborArray{i,j}),[]);
    end
end

% Show real parts of Gabor filters:
figure('NumberTitle','Off','Name','Real parts of Gabor filters');
for i = 1:u
    for j = 1:v        
        subplot(u,v,(i-1)*v+j);        
        imshow(real(gaborArray{i,j}),[]);
    end
end
```

Comment: To be honest, I implemented 2D gabor filter banks and then convolve it with my 2D image. But I want to know, is it possible to do it on a 3d image? even, I am not sure whether it is meaningful or not! :) anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am not 100 perct. sure, but it is not possible because gabor converts images to 2D. I dont know is there a 3D version of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a 3D gabor filter by extending the filter to 3 dimensions, so it becomes:

Gaussian(x,y,z)*exp(j*2p*(Ux+Vy+Zz)) .  For more info check out this paper:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320312003421#bib32